# onSaveInstanceState in Activity vs Custom View

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-custom-view

It seems that onSaveInstanceState when overridden in a custom View is not called if the activity that created the View also has onSaveInstanceState overridden. Why is this and is there a way to call both? Is one better to use than the other? Since not all Views are custom I find that it might be necessary to have the activity call onSavedInstanceState too.

In addition if you call it in the Custom View, how do you tell the activity to not perform the time consuming tasks, upon rotation, that were used to create the View in `onCreate` in the first place? The onSaveInstanceState in the View was used to stop the activity from performing time consuming tasks again and again.

Comment: Call `super.onSaveInstanceState` in the overridden `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: @DeeV In the Activity's onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: It's probably best to do it in both, but the Activity is the important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `super.onSaveInstanceState()` in your overridden method, it calls this method in all attached fragments and views.

It is a good practice to call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` every time you override it.